# Error al crear formulario "ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in Api::V2::FormsController#create" Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

### Contexto

Bueno, para poner en contexto,.. estoy realizando un mantenedor de formularios, donde el usuario puede ir agregando campos de forma dinamica (campo1, de tipo texto, campo2, number,,requerido,, ... etc).

### Descripción de error

Al momento de guardar un registro, me aparece este error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in Api::V2::FormsController#create

FormDetail(#69892243406740) expected, got {"mobile_activity_id"=>1, "label"=>"1", "is_required"=>true, "sort"=>1} which is an instance of ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#46931508206720)
Extracted source (around line #249):
```

acá es la linea donde marca el error, y que corresponde a los parametros que estoy enviando:
[image: error line]

### Código

Así es como tengo definidos los parametros:

```
def form_params
    params.permit(
      :reason_id,
      form_detail: [
        :mobile_activity_id,
        :label,
        :is_required,
        :sort,
        dynamic_cols: []
      ]
    )
  end
```

este es el modelo **form**

```
class Form < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "form"

  has_many :form_detail
  has_many :mobile_activity, through: :form_detail

  belongs_to :reason
  belongs_to :company

  validates :company, presence: true

  scope :of_active, lambda { |status| self.where(is_active: status) if status.present? }
  scope :of_company, lambda { |company_id| self.where(company_id: company_id) if company_id.present? }

  def self.createOnModel(data, company)
    @form = company.forms.create(data)
  end

  def self.modifyOnModel(data, company)
    @form = company.forms.update(data)
  end
end
```

Acá la funcion create del form_controller

##### POST /api/v2/forms

def create

```
@form = @current_company.forms.new(form_params)

return errors_response(@form.errors) unless @form.save

successful_response(@form, Api::V2::FormSerializer, :created)

@form_detail = @form.form_detail.create(
  form_params[:form_detail]
)
```

end

Este es el serializador form_serializer

```
class Api::V2::FormSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes(
    :id,
    :company_id,
    :reason_id,
    :is_active,
    :created_at,
    :updated_at,
    :is_deleted
    )
  has_many :form_detail
  has_many :mobile_activity
  belongs_to :reason
end
```

### Inspeccion de error:

Al inspeccionar en devTools, me aparece codigo 500.
[image: devTools]

Este es el payload:

```
{
    "reason_id": 58,
    "form_detail": [
        {
            "mobile_activity_id": 1,
            "label": "campo 1",
            "is_required": true,
            "dynamic_cols": [],
            "sort": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Espero me puedan echar una mano o darme alguna pista para resolverlo.
Gracias de antemano y saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu modelo `Form` deberías agregar

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :form_detail
```

aparte el parámetro a enviar debería llamarse `form_detail_attributes`, por lo cual debes cambiar:

```
def form_params
    params.permit(
      :reason_id,
      form_detail_attributes: [
        :mobile_activity_id,
        :label,
        :is_required,
        :sort,
        dynamic_cols: []
      ]
    )
  end
```

Y un detalle menor que no tiene relación con tu problema, pero la convención de rails dice que si usas un `has_many` el sujeto debería ir en plural, algo como:

```
  has_many :form_details
  has_many :mobile_activities, through: :form_details
```

Comment: tal cual. Gracias @alter-lagos